# ExtJS 4 display picture in modal window

Tags: image, extjs

In my application I use special key to call very simple window with only one element - image. This image is quite large so I set as a windows attributes:  maxHeight:  700 and autoScroll: true. Image definition is the following:

```
initComponent: function () {
    var me = this;

    Ext.apply(me, {
        items: [
            {
                xtype:      'image',
                src:        'obr/picture.jpg',
                shrinkWrap: true,
                mode:       'image'
            }
        ],
        dockedItems: [
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                    dock: 'bottom',
                    height: 40,
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype:   'tbfill'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype:   'button',
                            handler: me.onClose,
                            margin:  '0 10 0 0',
                            text:    'Close'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
    });
    this.callParent();
}
```

And when I click "Picture" button to call this window everytime I see the same (when application is "fresh", restarted). After first action I can see

[image]

(always) and when I press "Close" button and call it again I can see this window with picture in proper size. I can't find the reason, could you prompt me what's wrong?

I use ExtJS 4.2 and window definition is the following:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Picture', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.mywindow',

    requires: [
        'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar',
        'Ext.button.Button'
    ],

    resizable:  false,
    closable:   false,
    modal:      true,
    title:      'Nice picture...',
    maxHeight:  700,
    autoScroll: true,
...
```

Comment: What ExtJs version are you using and with what layout is the container configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close but event "load" don't work. Answer is here:

http://www.appfoundation.com/2012/08/ext-js-dynamic-image-refresh-and-load/

listener shout be:

```
listeners : {
        afterrender :  function(me){
            me.el.on({
                    load: function (evt, ele, opts) {
                        me.doComponentLayout();
                    }
                });
           }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

On load event of an `image` use `doLayout` method of the window, as image take some time to load.
Eg.:

`{
     xtype: 'image',
     src:        'obr/picture.jpg',
     shrinkWrap: true,
     mode:       'image',
     listeners: {
          load: function() {
               this.up('window').doLayout();
          }
     }
}`

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Unfortunatelly not, app can't run "load" (don't styop on debugger):               
{
                    xtype:      'image',
                    src:        'obr/co-to-piwo.jpg',
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    mode:       'image',
                    listeners: {
                        load: function() {
                            debugger;
                            this.up('window').doLayout();
                        }
                    }
                }